# How to prevent a project rebuild after modification of XML in MonoDroid?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

I'm currently having a issue with Mono for Android.

In my application I'm currently saving my variables between sessions using `SharedPreferences`.

Now whenever I have changed any of the XML or AXML files since the last build, the compiler will rebuild my entire project (clean->build). The deployment of the app will therefore always do the "Removing previous version" step first , be it on a emulator or a Android device. This will also remove all variables in the SharedPreferences class, resulting in having to reinitialize those pieces of data, which becomes very tedious if I'm working on the XML files.

Is there any way to prevent that the project will be rebuild if the XML files are modified. Or is there any way to prevent the SharedPreference data from being removed if the application gets re-installed?

Extra info:

- Build target: API 10
- Mono for Android Version:4.2.3
- IDE: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1
- Emulator: API 10 Atom x86 default emulator
- Device: Samsung Galaxy Wonder (Android 2.3.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rebuild is necessary when resource files change since it can result in a change to the generated Resource class. That said, Mono for Android does provide an option to preserve application data between deploys to help in situations like this.

If you look under Options-> Mono for Android you'll see a checkbox labeled "Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys" to turn on this feature.